# Adding GMSPanoramaView in subview or resizing it

Tags: ios, google-street-view

I am using google panorama street view in ios, But i am not able to put GMSPanoramaView in subview , it occupies whole screen .Please help me regarding this.Or is there any way that we can put it view with desired size so that it should not occupy whole screen.

Right now I am using following code :  and I am getting black screen while using this code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface NextViewController : UIViewController{

GMSPanoramaView *panoView_;


}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *sub_View;

@end

-(void)loadView{


panoView_ = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.sub_View = panoView_;

[panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.732, 150.312)];

}
```

Comment: Did you able to Do it?? I am also need to do similar functionality