# Google Maps iOS SDK - Add GMSPanoramaView in a SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view

I'm trying to add a GMSPanoramaView to a SubView.
Here is the code I'm working on :

```
panoView_ = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
panoView_.delegate = self;
self.view = panoView_;


[panoView_ moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(emplLatitude, emplLongitude)];
```

This code renders the panorama on fullscreen mode.

If I try this, nothing happens :

```
self.myView = panoView_;
```

Where myView outlet is set in my storyboard.

This stack is a possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818577/adding-gmspanoramaview-in-subview-or-resizing-it) which never got answered.

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works when panoView_ is NOT inited with CGRectZero

```
panoView_ = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 400, 400)];

self.myView.frame = panoView_.frame;
[self.myView addSubview:panoView_];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past.

Usually by setting the frame of the panoView_ to be that of the subview, it has worked for me:

```
self.myView.frame = panoView_.frame;
```

If that doesn't work, try checking to see if the panoView_ is in the subview's view hierarchy:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.myView.subviews);
```

You can then try adding it as a subview if needed:

```
[self.myView addSubview:panoView_];
```