# How to get Google Street View working inside a view in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have just recently started learning Swift and iOS development and I am trying to get Google Street View working on a Single View Application. So basically I was thinking to have a ViewController that has a view and inside the view I will have the StreetView view and a Button.

Following Google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview I can get everything working. It works when I do this:

```
self.view = panoView
```

Now, I am trying to achieve what I mentioned above with the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSPanoramaViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var panoramaView: GMSPanoramaView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.panoramaView.addSubview(panoView)
        self.panoramaView = panoView
        self.panoramaView.delegate = self

        panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude))

    }
}
```

And what I have in the storyboard is the following:
[image]
The only thing I can see is the refresh button.

I have also tried not setting the view as a GMSPanoramaView but only as a UIView, but that also didnt work

[image]

Can anyone point me to the right direction, please? Ultimately what I want is the StreetView covering all my screen and I want some buttons and some views on top of it.

I am using Xcode 6.1
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I added the function and can see the ID being printed out

```
func panoramaView(view: GMSPanoramaView!, didMoveToPanorama panorama: GMSPanorama!) {
        println(panorama.panoramaID)
    }
```

StreetView still empty

Comment: Implement the delegate method in order to check if something is missing (you add logs in this method) : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_panorama_view#afe910cfd418fdfa8646618140c54a05d : `panoramaView:didMoveToPanorama:nearCoordinate:` . About the full screen, you use constraints in the storyboards, and for the buttons on top of it, you place them also in the storyboard, you can use "Arrange" or the hierarchy in Document Outline.

Comment: Thanks. Ill have a look and update this post accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Paul - I've done what you asked func panoramaView(view: GMSPanoramaView!, didMoveToPanorama panorama: GMSPanorama!) {
        println(panorama.panoramaID)
    } and I can see the ID being printed on the console. Still... black screen. Any clues? 2015-02-19 12:53:44.159 GeoWhere[616:11592] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.9.14591.0
3l9omm45OWH48i3fCVSoig

Comment: Have you followed the steps here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start , maybe the most important, by using an API key with your app?

Comment: @Paul - Yes I have definitely followed everything to the dot. As I mentioned, I can see the map if I type "self.view = panoView" which is what described in the tutorial. But if I try to be a bit more "fancy" and add a View to the the ViewController's view (this is depicted in the image I posted here) then the map does not appear in that view. The project is very simple. Just a view under the ViewController's view and then simply initializing the view to "GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectZero)" Does not work. Have you by any chance tried to do that yourself at your end? Thanks so much

Comment: Hello, I had a look at the google map api, just follow these steps and it works fine : http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift . You import everything you need, you create a bridge header, you add the ios key, then you add a UIView to your storyboard, its class should be of type `GMSMapView`, and the whole thing worked for me.

Comment: @Paul Hi again. First of all, thanks for assisting me on this. I have indeed tried The Ray Wenderlich tutorial and it worked. But they are using Google Maps. I am  trying with Google Street View. 
I essentially tried changing the GMSMapsView that they set there in the view to GMSPanaromaView. I then type the code shown in the Google tutorial that I mentioned in this post and I get a blank screen. I simply don't know what could be wrong!

Comment: @Felipe Have you got the StreetView working yet ? Having the same exact issue here.

Comment: @Felipe Turned out the initial coordinate I entered was in the middle of the ocean, so no StreetView data, which is why it was stuck at loading.

Comment: @user2992766 yes I got it working. Unfortunately I had to programatically create all visual elements in the screen because I the only way I got Street View working was with self.view = panoView... did you do it differently? Were you able to put all elements in the storyboard? Would you be able to share this, please?

Comment: @Felipe see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545642/google-maps-ios-sdk-add-gmspanoramaview-in-a-subview/29217354#29217354